# Why do weird printers show up in the Ubuntu printing dialog?

Tags: 14.04, printing, system-settings

After upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 to 14.04 the system printing dialog shows printers I never installed:

[image]

"Farblaser" and "Laser" are printers I installed, the other two show up out of nowhere. Neither the CUPS web interface nor `system-config-printer` shows them, even with `View/Discovered Printers` enabled. `Browsing Off` is already in the CUPS config file. Printing dialogs other than the system one, e.g. Libreoffice (sic), don't show them either.

As it turns out, these *are* two network printers in our LAN. I can send print jobs to them, even though printing a PDF from evince results in the the PDF binary being printed -- ouch.

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/426848/69674), it's clear where the printer names come from; `avahi-browse -a | grep Printer` finds our network printers and assigns them IDs of the form `[BDxxxx]` which match the printer names (which I partly blurred out).

Disabling a whole service with multiple uses seems like overkill. How can I disable this behaviour of the printing dialog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation)

Comment: @BarafuAlbino I never experienced this behaviour with 13.04. The answers seem mostly ineffective, too; the issue does not seem to be with CUPS. `avahi-browse` seems to be a good lead; the device IDs is shows are `BDxxxx`, exactly the suffixes used in the printing dialog. However, just shutting the service down is clearly suboptimal. So my question stands and is unanswered: how to disable this behaviour *of the printing dialog*?

Comment: I think printing dialog only shows what it gets from CUPS, however I can't be sure anymore - Ubuntu gets overcomplicated with every new release.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino How can it come from CUPS if no other interface shows them? (No offense, but have you read the question, in particular the part below the picture?)

Comment: I can confirm this problem. If you are on a network with self-announcing printers, on 14.04, (some of?) those printers show automatically up in the print dialog (at least of Xubuntu and Kubuntu). Stopping `cups-browsed` prevents cups from adding those printers, but still, they show up in the print dialog. So yes, **this is not a cups problem**. The problem is resolved by stopping `avahi-deamon`, which is not optimal. We need a solution which keeps `avahi-deamon` alive, but stops the print dialog from displaying those printers.

Comment: What the f ....  I still see this problem with my 16.04 ... and worse: one can *delete* printers ... to watch them come back after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

As stopping the `avahi-daemon`or inserting `enable-dbus=no`into the `avahi-daemon.conf` did not help (16.04), we disabled the daemon on the interface which points to the network where the printers reside by adding `deny-interfaces=<interface>`to the `[server]` section of the config-file.

We could only do it because we do not need any avahi functionality there.