# Brother printer appears in application as an available printer but does not appear in Printer Settings or CUPS admin

Tags: drivers, 20.04, gnome, printing, brother

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04. Gnome. Wayland

I have a printer installed and visible when I select to print from my pdf viewer application.
(Brother-HL-L2390DW)
This printer must have an incorrect driver associated with it as every time I select to print from it, my printer just spits out dozens of blank pages.

However when I go to printer settings, this particular printer is not listed.  Nor do I see it when I pull up CUPS admin (http://localhost:631/)

Is there anyway I can either remove this printer (see highlited option) or at least update the driver to it? All other printers that appear in the list are valid/functional printers.

Coincidentally the other Brother printers that appear in this list, including the HL-L2390DW and Brother_HL_L2390DW both print fine.  I only have one physical instance of this printer.[image]

Comment: This is an issue with the GTK print dialog that is fixed in later versions of Ubuntu. It is annoying but not damaging.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/507099/why-do-weird-printers-show-up-in-the-ubuntu-printing-dialog