# ghost printer entry in printer dialogue after frozen installation process

Tags: 16.04, networking, printing, epson

I tried to install an Epson WF-2630 network printer on my fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation by using "Add" in the printer interface. First the installation window froze and I had to restart the computer. Then I installed the package lsb and the printer installed.

However, in the print dialogue of my documents there is an additional entry. Besides "print to file" and my installed "Epson" there ist an entry which reads:
"print - rejecting jobs" 
If I click on it, it says "getting more information on printer" indefinitely. 
Also, if I turn off the installed Epson printer the entry disappears and reappears if I turn the Epson printer on again.

In the Printers Interface on the computer there is no entry for an third printer.

I assume that this is the result of my crashed installation in the first place.

How do I fix this?

[image: Screenshot, the problematic entry is highlighted]

PS: the problem is similar to this one 
[How do I get rid of a ghost printer in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676863/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-ghost-printer-in-gnome)

However the solution doesn't work for me. 
I ran
`sudo gedit  /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`

and changed the enable-dbus=no 
but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printer is a network printer and not installed on my computer. Therefore the solution of [How do I get rid of a ghost printer in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676863/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-ghost-printer-in-gnome) applies. Though editing the avahi-daemon didn't work for me, this means that it is a network issue and not a problem of my computer.

Answer (score 0):

for a WF-2630 on 16.04, I would delete any existing icons for the 2630 from the PRINTERS folder, as they do not work. Then ...

download the Epson driver from here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=71623&DSCCHK=e1fdb812f3b09b3da605fd49ef90a9e43b62db49 by clicking the ACCEPT button and for 64bit Ubuntu click on the epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.20-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb. If one selects OPEN for download, gdebi installer should install the package; if one selects SAVE, then find the package in the **Downloads** folder and double-click to install.

That should 1) install the drivers and 2) trigger the printer to be registered in lpadmin and show up to print; if 2) does not occur automatically, create a new entry using ADD from the PRINTERS folder

Comment: seemed to have done the trick. Now it is installed over IPP. The other version worked as well, but with the entry like explained above.

Comment: sorry. the ghost entry is still there. didn't solve the problem.