# Doubled Printers in Settings/Devices/Printers

Tags: printing, 18.10, brother

My printer `Brother DCP-T510W`, connected via WiFi, got automatically detected by `Ubuntu 18.10`, but its functionality was limited (like for example scanning didn't work).
Decided to install manufacturer's dedicated linux driver - that resulted in additional printer entry in `Settings/Devices/Printers`, but this one is fully functional (the second one).

[image]

Tried to delete the first, automagically detected entry, but it comes back right after deletion (whaaa?).
**How can I get rid of the first entry then?**

Already tried:

- all cups related fixes found in net - didn't help (http://localhost:631/printers/ shows only the second entry though)
- avahi configuration `enable-dbus=no` fix - this disabled the first entry, but it resulted in significantly longer printer discovery and other software experiencing some hickups.

Comment: hmmm I think I remember you need to block avahi's automatic adding of printers. Probably a setting in  `/etc/default/avahi-daemon` (?)

Comment: Do you remember what setting was that? Excluding `enable-dbus=no` of course, because it slows down printer discovery significantly and seems to affect some other apps behavior too.

Comment: Hm  I might remembering it wrong. try `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf`  set `CreateIPPPrinterQueues` to `No`. Or just delete it with what DanyGee did. I might have done that too inthe end :X

Comment: All those `cups-browsed.conf` options seem to be ignored by the system. None helped to get rid of the first entry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of a ghost printer in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676863/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-ghost-printer-in-gnome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions might be just removing the avahi service by `sudo apt purge avahi-daemon`.
This results in proper, only one printer entry.
[image]

Comment: But this solution might have some drawbacks. I wonder what was avahi really useful for?