# Slow shutdown on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Stopping thermal daemon/running fit make remote CUPS printers)

Tags: shutdown, 16.04, error-handling

After a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I am experiencing very slow shutdowns compared with 15.10. There seems to be one of two processes that hang upon shutdown. Startup is not affected at all. When pressing (esc) the following are shown. Either:

"Stopping thermal daemon services" hangs, or
"A stop job is running for remote CUPS printers available locally", before a timer to 1 min 30 seconds is up, after which the machine finally shuts down.

Are there any other people experiencing this? This is most odd. What could be the reasons behind these two hangs?

Comment: Please check my recent [solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/896655/390708) as this bug has been fixed with `cups-filters` v1.11.4-1 yet not released in the Ubuntu 16.04 official repository. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 40):

I found that the daemon responsible for the CUPS remote printers is the cups-browsed service.

When shutting down, it has a time out of 1m 30s. Stopping this service causes the shutdown process to take only few seconds.

I disabled it using this command line on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04:

```
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
```

And my shutdown process ends in a few seconds.

I got the idea from [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/369122)

Comment: This worked for my non-clean 16.04 install! :-)

Comment: This was happening for a while, tested a few things like apport on/off, etc.  This actually worked, thanks!

Comment: This works only for the next shutdown. Doesn't persist.

Comment: I think disabling it altogether is not the solution if you really need this service. In my opinion the solution is given in [unhammer's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/810237/23468).

Comment: This is working on 17.10

Answer (score 28):

If you depend on network printers, you could simply make systemd a bit more aggressive in stopping the process. By default, it waits up to 1m30s before forcefully shutting things down, but you can just do

```
$ sudo systemctl edit cups-browsed.service
```

and enter

```
[Service]
TimeoutStopSec=10
```

to set the timeout down to 10. Then a

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

should make it take effect (or restart your computer).

This works great for me at least.

EDIT: According to [Xiaodong Qi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/896655/25639), cups-filters 1.11.4 has a fix for this, so upgrading past 17.04 Zesty ([which has cups-filters 1.13.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/cups-filters)) *should* be the simplest fix, though as commenters point out this workaround may still be needed :(

Comment: I think 2 seconds is enough

Comment: Probably; I have it set to 5 myself. It depends on how conservative you want to be (e.g. if you click "print" and immediately shut down, who knows if that SIGKILL could drop a slow print job – OTOH most people might expect to have to wait a bit with shutting down after clicking print).

Comment: This works only for the next shutdown. Doesn't persist.

Comment: Rajesh Paul, that's odd; does `cat /etc/systemd/system/cups-browsed.service.d/override.conf` show the same contents as above? Is this also on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: For some reason, the "code" formatting here turns some of my /-symbols into garbage; you can try `cd /etc/systemd/system/cups-browsed.service.d && cat override.conf`

Comment: According to [cups-browsed causes shutdown hang/delay in Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/1579905) has been fixed by now in 16.04, yet it still hangs. I double checked, and I have the "fixed" package install. Weird.  In my opinion the solution is your answer; it really helped me.

Comment: Note about the "EDIT", this still happens in Zesty (at least on my dell XPS)

Comment: FYI: still an issue in Eoan 19.10

Answer (score 21):

I have got the same Problem. It occurred after clean install Ubuntu 16.04. Finally I figured out, after lots of troubleshooting, that (after disable the Ubuntu boot splash screen) a certain stop-job was running that made the shutdown slow. (Thanks to Alex!) Then I got this error report:

```
a stop job is running for make remote cups printers available locally
```

Then I tried this:

```
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed.service
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
```

To verify:

```
sudo systemctl status cups-browsed
sudo systemctl is-enabled cups-browsed
```

and it finally worked! Shutdown was now as good and fast as ever. (You can find this troubleshooting on: "The Annoying Cups Browsed" at the ec-cwang´s Blog!)

This might be important for those this solution is not helpful: How to find out your running stop jobs, just look up: "How do I disable the boot splash screen" on Ask Ubuntu. Then, if you start Ubuntu you get the typical Linux running command signs. If you shut Ubuntu down, mention the output. It shows you at the end what kind of stop job slows down your shutdown procedure.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this when I have upgraded again (currently downgraded back to 15.10  due to other issues)

Comment: very likely the solution, since `.. stop cups-browsed.service` takes *ages* in the console.

Comment: I think disabling it altogether is not the solution if you really need this service. In my opinion the solution is given in [unhammer's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/810237/23468).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. After checking everything, I found out that if uncheck "**enable wireless**" (right button on wifi icon), and restart, it takes 5 seconds. If i leave wireless active shutdown takes about 1 minute.

I have a USB wifi adapter TP-LINK. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Almost identical problem after clean update from 15.10. I have finetuned different programs/properties including made an attemmpt installing my wifi cup printer. Most seems to work, but shutdown takes more then 3 minutes. Pressing f12 shows end endless textloop: 
OK Start showing plymouth reboot screen
OK Stopped thermal daemon service.
Can I somehow get a log of the shutdown proces?
2: SOLVED. After installing the printer correctly everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue. Turned out to be caused by Private Internet Access client. I had enabled "Start application at login". After disabling this feature, shutdown is almost instant.

Answer (score 0):

Up until now, this bug should be fixed upon the recent release of the `CUPS-filters` (v1.11.4+) package related to two issues of `CUPS`--[this one](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=832637) and [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/1579905). It requires to install `CUPS-filters` version 1.11.4-1 or above according to [this discussion](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=832637). However, it requires `CUPS` version 2.2.0+, and in fact the working `CUPS-filters` and `CUPS-core` versions haven't been released in the Ubuntu 16.04 repository so far. If you are still having this issue, you might want to try downloading the corresponding [CUPS-filters](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters) and its dependencies (including `libcups2`, `cups-ipp-utils` and others) from the [Zesty's repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/cups-filters)
 (for example, with [this version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/1.13.4-1ubuntu1)) and install the downloaded `deb` packages using the `dpkg` command like:

```
 sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libcups2_2.2.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
 sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/cups-ipp-utils_2.2.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
 sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/cups-filters-core-drivers_1.13.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
 sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libcupsfilters1_1.13.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
 sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/cups-filters_1.13.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I am only giving command lines as a template for you to install the dependencies and the `CUPS-filters` deb packages. Feel free to download the package from elsewhere with a different version (has to be ~>1.11.4 for `CUPS-filters`).  You may find you would need to install a lot of other dependencies and fix the incompatibility problems with the corresponding i386 and amd64 versions of those packages in your case. You should download packages with the same version number for all dependent packages. For instance, all [cups](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/cups) related packages as linked should be chosen to have the same version number [2.2.2-1ubuntu1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/2.2.2-1ubuntu1) or otherwise. Then those related binary packages should be downloaded from the [Binary Packages section from the same page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/2.2.2-1ubuntu1). If you find there are two package which cannot be configured simultaneously, don't worry and you should be able to configure them automatically using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` after you install all other packages.

Alternatively, you can temporarily change your update source list to Zesty (Ubuntu 17.04) or most recent distribute and then install required CUPS packages using `sudo apt update && sudo apt install PACKAGE` where you should replace the keyword `PACKAGE` for the name of packages you want to upgrade to the latest version. Don't forget to change the source list back after this partial upgrade. But this method may make you break other things if you are not doing it correctly.

This is how I fixed this problem on my Ubuntu 16.04. YMMV.

***PS***:

1. If your printing jobs cannot be stopped, you can use `cancel -a` to cancel all printing jobs.
2. If you still encounter this issue after the last fix on Ubuntu, please report this bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/1703968) directly to developers. They will look into this issue more closely.

Comment: Does that mean the bug is no more in 17.04, making these workarounds unnecessary?

Comment: I haven't tried 17.04, but if you find the version number of CUPS-filter is newer than 1.11.4, the problem with CUPS should be fixed and then you don't need to go over the workaround.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/cups-filters seems that way =D

Comment: According to [cups-browsed causes shutdown hang/delay in Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/1579905) has been fixed by now in 16.04, yet it still hangs. I double checked, and I have the "fixed" package install. Weird.  In my opinion the solution is given in [unhammer's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/810237/23468); that helped me.

Comment: My personal guess is there might have been multiple issue with CUPS, or the fix doesn't really fix the problem for a broader case. The fixed bug is to shut down the service once the computer verified the printing service based on my understanding. @unhammer's answer basically set up a short shutdowntime if the service is still running when shutting down the computer. I'll report this to developers. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/1703968) again. I appreciate if people encountered this issue after the last fix can report there. Thanks!