# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS occasional slow restart and shutdown

Tags: boot, 16.04, shutdown, restart

Occasionally when restarting or shutting down (about 1 out of 5 times) the PC takes about 1-2 minutes to restart instead of the usual 2-3 seconds.

This screen appears and keeps loading something until it shuts down after a minute or two.
[image]

I have no idea what is causing this, initially I thought maybe it's updates that are being finalised. But It happens even when I haven't installed anything and it's hard to pinpoint exactly when it happens.

Comment: switch to console mode and check where it stops.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is because there are applications that have open files. A sure-fire way to test this is for you to close all applications before shutting down and restarting.

Answer (score -1):

Some other people have found this to be caused by the CUPS software (related to remote printers) here: [Slow shutdown on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Stopping thermal daemon/running fit make remote CUPS printers)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760952/slow-shutdown-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-stopping-thermal-daemon-running-fit-make-remo)

If that's what the problem is for you too, the short answer is:

`sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service`