# Shutdown is so slow in16.04

Tags: shutdown

Shutdown is taking about 6-7 minutes. Especially: **A stop job is running for ccpd.service 5 min 6s** 
what should I do?

Comment: Check this: [Slow shutdown on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Stopping thermal daemon/running fit make remote CUPS printers)](//askubuntu.com/q/760952)

Comment: Do you have a Canon printer?

Comment: Yes, I have Canon LBP6000. I installed drivers but it doesn't work(

Comment: How do you know which job is running?

Comment: @jarno It is shown while the system is shutting down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ccpd = Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS

On a system with Linux MINT 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.4 LTS) and a Canon LBP7210C network printer, I did this for a faster timeout to take precedence.

Edit the *override.conf* file

```
$ sudo systemctl edit ccpd.service
```

and enter

```
[Service]
TimeoutStopSec=10
```

to set the timeout to 10 seconds. Save and exit. 
This change will prevail between each shutdown.

To check the modified timeout value, run

```
$ systemctl show ccpd.service -p TimeoutStopUSec
TimeoutStopUSec=10s
```

The same method was used in this post https://askubuntu.com/a/810237 for a different service.

Note: Each service has a timeout and its there for a reason. Changing the timeout for a network printer seems OK. For other services (eg: disk drives) the effect of changing a preset value must be carefully considered.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an old bug as reported here: ([a stop job is running for login service](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207408))

There are lots of solutions discussed but this worked for the OP:

```
systemctl isolate multi-users.target

reboot
```

**Edit** - Just read the commented link posted under question here. It appears more accurate and if so comment below this answer so I can delete it. Thank you.