# Ubuntu 16.04: Slow shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 in my Thinkpad 470s. After two days when I logged in, I got a message that there was a system problem detected and if I wan to report that. I  select yes and it asked me to put my password to report the problem. But since then the shutting down process became very slow.
Any suggestion what can I do?

Comment: Does this happen when shutting down from the top-right button only? Could you try running 'sudo shutdown' in a terminal and seeing if any warning is shown?

Comment: No warning is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The solution mention [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760952/slow-shutdown-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-stopping-thermal-daemon-running-fit-make-remo) solved this problem.

```
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
```