# ubuntu 16.04 slow shutdown

Tags: 16.04

Recently I noted that it takes more than 5 min without completely shutdown which usually takes a few sec.

I usually long press the power button to force shut down & sometimes I just leave it to shut down eventually.

Is there something I can do to rectify the problem? Please help.

Regards,
Frank

Comment: Press [Esc] while it is showing the shutdown animation to see the log messages. Probably there will be something like "A stop job is running for xxxxx...". Can you report back what you see?

Comment: Long-press the power button is unwise. You can corrupt your filesystem that way.

Comment: Don't know what I've done, after removing a few apps & deleting some files. Now it works ok, ie shutdown in a couple of sec. Problem appears to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Some other people have found this to be caused by the CUPS software (related to remote printers) here: [Slow shutdown on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Stopping thermal daemon/running fit make remote CUPS printers)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760952/slow-shutdown-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-stopping-thermal-daemon-running-fit-make-remo)

If that's what the problem is for you too, the short answer is:

`sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service`