# Ubuntu 18.04 takes long time to shutdown/restart/logout

Tags: shutdown, lenovo, 18.04, restart, logout

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my lenovo Ideapad y520. It is taking very long to shutdow/restart/logoff. It freezes sometimes and I need to shutdown system using power button. Has anyone gone through this issue?

Please help!!!!!Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue on Dell Vostro 5568. I occasionally force reboot if nothing happens for several minutes.

Comment: Try to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: When leaving ubuntu, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to see what's take a long time. Sometimes it's CUPS (https://askubuntu.com/questions/760952/slow-shutdown-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-stopping-thermal-daemon-running-fit-make-remo)

Comment: same device here. ubuntu is a disaster overall on my hardware. it can shutdown and restart but it takes about 2-3 minutes before it happens. first the desktop hangs then something pops up in the terminal that something needs to wait 59 secs to kill....

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact reason but using NVIDIA drivers instead of xorg drivers helped me