# how to prevent CUPS from proposing printers that are not listed in printer.conf?

Tags: printing

My `printers.conf` contains a short list of printers. When I open the *Print* menu of any application, a longer list of printers is shown. Besides those from `printers.conf`, there are some more from our corporate network. Through which mechanism does CUPS find those printers, which configuration files and parameters control this behavior, and how to switch it off?

My PC is fully administered by myself; it's running plain Debian. So the printer list is not pushed by the corporate IT. Rather my PC has retrieved this list from the network - against my intent, by some hidden mechanism.

[cross-posting from Unix&Linux, where there seems to be little interest]

Comment: The mechanism might be "DNS Service Discovery" (DNS-SD). Installing `mdns-scan` will help you see "available" services.  Can you delete the printers (from your `cupsd`) through `http://localhost:631/printers`? NOTE: Do NOT edit `/etc/cups/printers.conf` when the CUPS daemon is running (`sudo service cups stop` ). Read ` man cups-browsed` and `man cups-browsed.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `cups-browsed` was installed. I stopped the services `cups` and `cups-browsed`, uninstalled the package `cups-browsed`, rebooted, and found clean print menus as defined by `/etc/cups/printers.conf`.

Clues came from @waltinator and from [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083).

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326916/46841: disable the switch `Browsing` in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`.