# How to block sending of SNMP broadcasts to the network?

Tags: networking, firewall, snmp, 18.10

Our administrators notified me that my machine is bothering the corporate network with SNMP broadcasts.

I suspected CUPS, removed all printers from the config and tried everything shown here: [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation/556963) 
(Avahi config, CUPS config, setting /etc/cups/snmp.conf Address to 127.0.0.1)
Nothing helped.

Probably another service is sending SNMP broadcasts? Can you name some local firewall rule for Ubuntu 18.10 to simply block all SNMP broadcasts?