# 100% CPU usage and overheating issue when Wi-Fi is on in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, asus, overheating

In my laptop (Asus VivoBook, i5 8th gen, 256GB+1TB, 8GB ram), using Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot with Windows 10), it was showing 100% CPU used when Wi-Fi is on (no other processes were running). So that the laptop temperature was unnecessarily increasing and consumed power.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: 40°C-60°C is fine, I would be more concerned at 70°C-80°C.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it is solved by stopping the `cups-browsed`, detailed steps are given below:

1. Install nethogs:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nethogs
   ```

   followed by

   ```
   sudo nethogs wlan0
   ```
2. It was showing that some process is running through the Wi-Fi, called `/usr/sbin/cups-browsed`, which is basically searching the wireless printers and devices.
3. For that we have to stop `cups-browsed` as follows

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
   sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed
   ```

   Output will look like:

   ```
   Synchronizing state of cups-browsed.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
   Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable cups-browsed
   ```
4. You may still start/stop the service manually if you wish, as given in the link [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/345083/):

   ```
   sudo systemctl start cups-browsed  
   sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
   ```

Comment: Welcome to **Ask Ubuntu**. Thank you for moving your answer out of your question. I've edited your answer for proper code block formatting and upvoted both your Q. and your A. so you have more points.

Comment: Now the question and answer don't match. The first part of this answer should actually be the question. I'm going to fix it. If you still need to ask for a solution of the "temperature is showing 40-60 deg *even after* trying the steps in this answer", consider asking a new question with the link to this one.