# Macbooks Printers

Tags: 18.04, printing, macbook

I don't know the first thing about Macbooks, or any apple product for that matter, so I have no idea why Ubuntu is doing this. Sitting in campus core I keep getting these popups that a printer has been added. When I looked at my printers page, this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, there are a lot of printers installed this way, and they are all from Macbooks. I did not tell it to do this, and I don't want it to do this. How do I stop it?

P.S. I'm also not allowed to use the ubuntu tag? on askubuntu? for reasons?

Comment: Most likely someone (actually from the sight of it, three people Stephen Huff, Kishan and "Man") on the campus network has a MacBook that has a printer setup as being shared.  These MacBooks broadcast the fact that they have shared printers, and your Ubuntu machine picks this up.  You cannot do anything against it, except for finding these people and hitting them on the head (not literally please).  It seems that MacBooks do this by default for some stupid reason. The same thing can happen with any PC (Linux,Windows,Mac,BSD) that have been configured as sharing printers.

Comment: That explains the why, but not how to avoid this.  I don't have this problem, so I cannot give you first hand experience, but a quick search turned up this Ask Ubuntu:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation/

I would suggest trying the `BrowseProtocols none`  solution.  That one looks to me as being the most likely one to work and stay working

Comment: Do note, that when you when you set `BrowseProtocols` to  `none`, it will also stop detecting legit printers.  This might not be a problem on the campus network. but on your home network you might want auto detection.
The configuration mistake remains on the side of the MacBook users, in my opinion.

Comment: @GuinevereEllenMayberry please edit your comment to remove the expletive. It adds nothing to the thread.