# Network printer appearing twice under "Settings > Printer"

Tags: networking, 20.04, printing, hp

I have a network printer, a HP ENVY, and for some reason, it always appears 2 times (sometimes even 3 times) in the list.

Another weird thing that happens is that every night, exactly at 00:00, a pop up message appears, saying that my printer has been discovered in the network.

Why is this happening? What could I do to stop this weird behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation) This is an ongoing issue through many versions but the resolution remains the same.

Comment: I do not want to disable remote configuration. I want it to work properly.

Comment: Which application is the list in the screenshot obtained from?

Comment: Stop cups-browsed (`systemctl stop cups-browsed`) and say which entries disappear from the list.

Comment: Do both entries in the list work for printing?

Comment: @brian_p The second one disappeared. I dont think both work, but now Im not sure anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second print queue disappearing implies that it is being auto-setup by cups-browsed. It should reappear when cups-browsed is restarted. This part of remote configuration **is working correctly and as designed**.

The first queue is not set up by cups-browsed but by the GTK printing sub-system. I am guessing that the screenshot shows a GTK application. (You did not say what the application is).

GTK gets remote printers all by itself. **It does not use CUPS** but deals directly with the printer. My guess is that when CUPS is stopped (`systemctl stop cups`) the first entry still does not disappear.

The issue of GTK not using the correct CUPS APIs may be seen as a bug. There is nothing you can do about the first entry without severely crippling your whole printing system, which is what some of the advice in [@User24601's link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation) advocates. Users will have to live with it until the GTK maintainers decide to fit in with what CUPS provides.

Informative links are [here](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSPrintQueues#gtk) and [here.](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#gtk)

Comment: I restarted cups-browsed and the printer did not return, but I will keep an eye for it tomorrow morning. Thanks!