# How to stop automatic printer detection?

Tags: networking, printing

I have a desktop computer running Ubuntu 20.04 on a LAN. Thus automatically adds all the printers it finds in the LAN which are in other rooms/offices. How to stop the automatic addition of printers?

Existing solutions do not work in Ubuntu 20.04 as mentioned in their comments.

[How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/345083/1107236)

Comment: "as mentioned in their comments" or did all those solutions on that page actually all fail for you? A bunch of the answers on that page have comments that say an answer worked for them in 20.04. Are you flushing caches/rebooting after trying them?