# Howto disable autodiscovery printers

Tags: networking, printing

I've read several threads on the subject but none solves it.

In practice, under Win if one does not want to have a list of all the printers on the network, for example 50 (and you can physically use 2), there is a button to press in printer configuration, you can remove printers that you don't need.
If you add a printer you can select from total list.

I have tried all these operations:
http://localhost:631/admin/ → Edit Configuration File or Edit /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
Changed:
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
To:
Browsing Off
BrowseLocalProtocols none
and reboot

Not resolve

Changing
/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf
Change this line:
BrowseRemoteProtocols dnssd cups
To:
BrowseRemoteProtocols none
and reboot

Not resolve

sudo cupsctl --no-share-printers
Disable everything but does not keep the two you need that you have to reset by hand, because you don't even see them in the 'add printer'.
But also changing
/etc/cups/cupsd.conf
and setting
Browsing Off
Entering the problem remain the same.

sudo service avahi-daemon stop

Don't resolve

This could easily be solved with a button 'hide printer' command and a window showing hidden printers would be enough to show them again.
If you remove the printer it reappears.

It's an important thing in any big company I don't understand how it can't be done as easily as in Win.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation)

Comment: I had read these posts and the experiments are those indicated but nothing solves the problem